# why PSNR of distorted image is greater?

Tags: matlab

TI am confused with Peak signal-to-noise ratio (PSNR) between original image and distorted image. I know higher PSNR means the better image quality.

1) First i compare distorted image with another jpeg image, It results with 26.77 dB.

2) Then i remove noise from distorted image and again compare then it results low psnr ie 26.20 dB..`

Anyone can correct with me my mistake that why PSNR of distorted image is higher?`

Attaching Psnr Code

```
grayImage = imread('img84.jpeg');

I=rgb2gray(grayImage);

% I=rgb2gray(grayImage);

[rows columns] = size(grayImage);

Display the first image.

subplot(2, 2, 1);

imshow(grayImage, []);

title('YUV Frame ', 'FontSize', fontSize);

set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize')); % Maximize figure.

Get a second image by adding noise to the first image.

noisyImage = imread('frame84.jpg');

J=rgb2gray(noisyImage);

[rows columns] = size(noisyImage);

Display the second image.

subplot(2, 2, 2);

imshow(noisyImage, []);

title('Before Processing', 'FontSize', fontSize);

------ PSNR CALCULATION ----------------------------------------------------------

squaredErrorImage = (double(grayImage) - double(noisyImage)) .^ 2;

title('Squared Error Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);

mse = sum(squaredErrorImage(:)) / (rows * columns);

Calculate PSNR (Peak Signal to Noise Ratio) from the MSE according to the formula.

PSNR = 10 * log10( 256^2 / mse);

message = sprintf('The mean square error is %.2f.\nThe PSNR = %.2f', mse, PSNR);

msgbox(message);
```

[image: I attached the output Images.Before and after processing]

Comment: I’ve tried formatting your code as code, so we can read it. However, it seems that it has bits of text mixed in. Please [edit] your question to properly format the code and the text. Thanks!

Comment: You don’t show your code for noise reduction. That is probably where your error is. You should show the minimum amount of code needed for us to reproduce your problem. That includes posting the pictures you read in (not the screen shot). See [mcve].